# How(/if) to use dask to transpose distributed 3D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, mpi, dask

My problem is to perform 3 matrix multiplications on a 3D numpy array A too large to fit in a single processor. In tensorial form I want A_ijk B_km C_jn D_ip (B, C, and D can all fit in memory). I want to know if dask is appropriate for this task (or if another tool might be more suited).

I believe the best approach is to split this operation into each multiplication, and make sure that they are all local. This link has a really useful diagram that summarises what I'm talking about http://www.2decomp.org/1d_mode.html.

In more detail: First, to do A_ijk B_km, I should distribute A over the first two axes, and perform the matrix multiplication over each pencil locally (the first step in the diagram).

Then, I need to transpose the array, making the j axis local to each processor (and splitting over the k (now m) axis), to then perform the next multiplication. (So going from the first to the second step in the diagram). This is where I wonder if dask could help.

I'm aware that this can be done in principle using mpi4py, but the steps are pretty non-trivial, whereas dask arrays have helpful rechunk and transpose methods, which feel relevant to this application.

Does this seem like something well-suited to dask?

If not, is anyone aware of any python libraries that can perform these steps? I know that [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/FFTW-MPI-Transposes.html#FFTW-MPI-Transposes) has routines for doing just this, but I don't know how to write the C-code necessary, or how to get it to interface with python and numpy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else in the future, mpi4py does have a transpose method. But it's called Alltoall/Alltoallv. It's not explained in the documentation or tutorial on mpi4py. I found out about it at another tutorial: https://info.gwdg.de/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:hpc:mpi4py.

Answer (score 0):

Dask implements [einsum](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.einsum), which may be what you are after, and there is, of course [matmul](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.matmul), if you want to write out the operation. So long as your large matrix `A` is a Dask array, with reasonable chunk sizes, Dask will parcel out your work without running out of memory.